# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object.

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I know this question has been asked for a number of times, but solutions I read don't work out in my case. My codes are super simple and straightforward:

```
// Import a library to help create a component
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

//Only access text and AppRegistry from React-native lib

//Create a component
const App = () => (
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
);

//Render it to the device
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp2_albums', () => App);
```

I am using expo to develop ios app. It keeps showing Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of ‘AwakeInDevApp’

Any insight would be appreciated:)

Comment: Maybe it's unrelated but your `App` function isn't returning the `Text` component.

Comment: I've tried a sample solution and it seems to work just fine? Are you sure your issue is here?

Comment: Maybe you could try adding `export default App;` before you render it to the device.

Comment: @MinusFour The online instructor says this syntax can ignore the return.

Comment: @RyanTurnbull I don't know. I typed the same codes as in the online course but it didn't work out. What sample solution did u try?

Comment: @kakamg0 I tried, now it says expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React native can sometimes be picky about wrapping your fields within a view and give it a flex of 1.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

//Only access text and AppRegistry from React-native lib

//Create a component
  export default const App = () => {
  return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
       <Text>Some Text</Text>
   </View>
  );
};

//Render it to the device
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp2_albums', () => App);
```